# process.env.NODE_ENV === development in heroku, but should be === production

Tags: heroku

When I deploy my application to Heroku the server address localhost:8080 used to retrieve my content, however, this shouldn't be the case because of the following condition

```
let Server;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  Server = "https://yana-scheduler.herokuapp.com/api/people";
} else {
  Server = "http://localhost:8080/api/people";
}
export default Server;
```

It seems process.env.NODE_ENV isn't firing but also when I console.log (process.env.NODE_ENV) I GET "development"

Comment: In title you say `=== development` but in your code you show `=== "production"`. So which one is it? If `NODE_ENV` is not set to `production` by default it is because you overwrote it.

Comment: Hello @TinNguyen when I console log (process.env.NODE_ENV) I get development. The title of my post is just an explanation of what is going on. Thank you